# Disable anchor link failed with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have anchor tag

```
<a id="click" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="disable();" style="">Clickme</a>.
```

When html loads it showing clickme,when i click anchor link,it calls `disable()` function,In disable function i am trying to hide it using below code:

```
document.getElementById("click").style.display='none';
```

But page never hides that anchor link,Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a link can be hidden (without being wrapped in a div) but if it could the code would be

```
document.getElementById("click").style.visibility='hidden'
```

Comment: Am sure display style property will work for anchor element too.