# How to hide anchor link with Jquery

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable anchor link failed with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550313/disable-anchor-link-failed-with-javascript)

I have anchor tag

```
<a id="click" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="disable();" style="">Clickme</a>.
```

When html loads it showing clickme,when i click anchor link,it calls disable() function,In disable function i am trying to hide it using below code within the jquery success function:

```
document.getElementById("click").style.display='none';
```

But page never hides that anchor link,Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do two things: 1) Revise existing questions instead of asking duplicates.  2) Accept some answers.

Comment: If you already use jQuery, use it consistently. Btw in your original question you don't state that you use jQuery.

Comment: Post the code for `disable()` function, you're doing something wrong in there.

Answer (score 5):

if you have the id of the anchor you can use `$('#ID').hide()` to hide it and to show it use `$('#ID').show()`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments,i tried with above solution ,but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using jQuery, you can follow unobtrusive way of coding

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a id="click" href="#">Clickme</a>
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DtVyG/)

If this is not working then check your HTML. If there is more than one element with the same id then the HTML will be invalid and your script wont work properly.

Comment: >> If there is more than one element with the same id then the HTML will be invalid - I can't believe I fell for that again.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your coding style I'd say you used the same ID for other elements(anchors) too. You should never put more than one ID value on the same page.